# How to remove width attribute which is under style attribute using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="views" style="position: relative; width: 421px; height: 15px; overflow: hidden;">
TEST TEXT
</div>
```

How to remove width attribute which is under style attribute using jQuery?

**I know removeAttr("width");**

**But it will not work here because width is child of style attribute**

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You could use:

```
.css('width', 'auto')
```

Comment: I usually do $node[0].style.width='' for single elements. Most of the time I need to reset the width or height for animation purposes on one element

Comment: No, this won't remove width attribute but set it's another value which is auto.

Answer (score 73):

As easy as

```
$('div.views').css('width', '');
```

Comment: Thank you, i knew this but sometimes you need second eyes on problem... :D

Comment: Thanks. Easy? yes. Intuitive? no.

Answer (score 23):

This also worked here:

```
$(".views").width("");
```

Comment: This would reset it's value. This is correct way.

Answer (score 7):

Don't use inline styles. Use classes.

```
$(".views").removeClass("a");
$(".views").addClass("b");
```

But if you really want to, you could do the following:

```
$(".views").css("width", "");
```

Comment: I don't use inline, but I still wanted to remove inline width which was previously added via js.

Comment: If the width is being measured eg for a responsive table where the columns need to be measured then you can't use classes.

Answer (score 2):

A slightly-shorter version of [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7995541/937377):

```
.width('auto')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you must try this:

`$(".views").removeAttr('style').attr('style','position: relative; height: 15px; overflow: hidden;');`

Comment: Offcourse the Best way is to use Classes than Inline Styles.You can define 2 classes with Different attribute and add or remove them when required.

Comment: If the width is being measured based on the width of something else then you can't use a class. Also, removing the style attribute may remove other inline styles you have set eg by using .hide()or .show()

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with CSS only:

```
div[style="position: absolute; top: -136px; overflow: auto; width:1241px;"] {
width: 0px !important;
display: none !important;
```

}