# Reach an html div with inside a tree structure with css

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have the following html structure (inside a wiki-content div) and I don't know how to reach it.

[image]

This doesn't seem to work, would you know why?

```
.wiki-content .table-wrap relative-table.wrapped.confluenceTable
{
   width: 100%;
 }
```

Thank you

Comment: did you put that inline style in that table?

Comment: You're missing `.` before 'relative-table'

Comment: yes, I guess that the issue. Though I don't generate that code, it is a Confluence wiki

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesnt work because you have an inline CSS value of width set to 99.9315%. Inline styles get processed after your css so this will override any other setting for width in your css file.

Try removing the inline width setting.

Comment: I see, it makes sense based on what I see when I debug. Are you talking about this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7995491/how-to-remove-width-attribute-which-is-under-style-atttribute-using-jquery. It seems it would affect all the code?

Comment: Not exactly. I mean you should remove the inline width setting completely from HTML. Currently when your website loads you will have two width settings (one in HTML and one in CSS) and only one (in HTML) will be accepted. If you need to change width on the fly you can use Javascript/JQuery to select your div and change the width - https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/.

Comment: I see, thank you. In that case afraid I cannot do anything as Confluence allows me to just change the CSS, not the code itself

Comment: Sure, please accept if you feel this has answered your question

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `!important`?

```
.wiki-content .table-wrap relative-table.wrapped.confluenceTable
{
   width: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Your `relative-table` must be `.relative-table`

Comment: Thanks. No luck unfortunately

Comment: Are you sure it's `.wiki-content`? not `.plugin-tabmeta-details`?

Comment: I do not know for `.plugin-tabmeta-details` - tbh I am using `.wiki-content` as all other css definitions use it. Will give it a try

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing this and the try to put `!important` to override the existing width.

```
.table-wrap .relative-table.wrapped.confluenceTable
{
   width: 100%!important;
}
```

If the inline style width is generated by a certain javascript, you need to re initialized it using also a javascript. because you can't override a inline style using css since it has the most specificity value. Please read this link about https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Please see below javascript code to re initialized the width.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("relative-table").style.width = "100%";
```